# Ionic Components no funcionan

Tags: ionic, angularjs-2.0, typescript, ionic2

Buenas a todos.

Estoy empezando una app con Ionic. Y estoy tratando de utilizar los componentes que trae Ionic por defecto desde código.

> http://ionicframework.com/docs/components

Entiendo que me falta importar algún tipo de librería o similar ya que actualmente no funciona. Si yo pongo

`<button class="button button-dark">Prueba</button>`

Tal y como se especifica en el enlace que he pasado antes:

> http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#buttons

`<button class="button button-dark">
  button-dark
</button>`

No funciona visualmente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
¿Alguna idea de que es lo que hago mal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

intenta usando las directivas de ionic framework como lo muestro a continuación:

```
<button ion-button color="dark">Dark</button>
```

Puedes ver más ejemplos en:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#buttons o https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/button/Button/

Espero te sirva, saludos! :D

Comment: Di con ellas al final de la tarde de ayer jejeje. Iba a autocontestarme esta mañana pero se me paso. Es justamente eso lo que necesitaba. Gracias.

Comment: De nada, que bueno que ya lo solucionaste, saludos! ;)